# Manage links in Sharepoint

Tags: url

I've a big Sharepoint Publishing site with many pages and sites. There are many external list that should be managed. My problem here is when a external link (to a specific website or resource) changes the address, I should go in every page where this link is located and make the correction. Is there any out of the box feature or other possibility to manage all links from one page?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your pain point here. But it is a tough choice here. If you have page layouts based on which these pages are created, and if these links are static on these page layouts you can change these links on the page layouts from which the page derive from.

But there is no straight forward to change the links all at once, if you have links on different pages and sites. Hope this helps.